# Applying filter to a observableArray?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a project where I have a search field that filters an observableArray based on what is typed in the search box.

Here is my html code:

```
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a burger joint around downtown Indianapolis, IN" data-bind="value: searchInput, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keyup: filterResults }">
```

Here is my js code:

```
var BurgerJoint = function(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.long = ko.observable(data.long);
    this.lat = ko.observable(data.lat);
    this.comments = ko.observable(data.comments);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.searchInput = ko.observable('');

    this.burgerList = ko.observableArray([]);

    initialBurgerJoints.forEach(function(burgerItem){
        self.burgerList.push( new BurgerJoint(burgerItem) );        
        addmarker(burgerItem.lat, burgerItem.long, burgerItem.id, burgerItem.name, burgerItem.comments);
    });

    self.burgerList.sort(function (l, r) { return l.name() > r.name() ? 1 : -1 });

    self.currentFilter = ko.observable();

    self.filterResults = function(){
        var value = self.searchInput().toLowerCase();
        if(value != ''){
            self.burgerList(self.burgerList.filter(function(data){
                var startsWith = data.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value);
                return burgerList;
            }));
        }
        return true;
    };

    self.showmap = function(data) {
        viewmarker(data.id());
    };      
}

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I'm having issues with the filterResults function.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `I'm having issues with the filterResults function`. What issues are you having? Do you get an error? An unexpected result? What is your expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you shouldn't set your original `burgerList` in filter function. Make a copy/clone of the original first. Try something like

```
    self.filterResults = function(){
        var value = self.searchInput().toLowerCase();
        if(value != ''){
            self.burgerList(self.burgerList().filter(function(data){
                return data.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value);
            }));
        }else{
          // reset with the original burgerList contents here
          self.burgerList(self.burgerListClone());
        }
    };
```

Comment: This is what a `computed` is for.

Comment: Would you happen to have example using computed?

Comment: I'm getting an error with your code sample:
Uncaught TypeError: data.name.toLowerCase is not a function

I'm also using KnockoutJS 3.2.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to revise one of your lines of code:

return data.name().toLowerCase().startsWith(value);